# PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS not working with batch insert

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Prepared Statement with return generated keys is returning the auto generated key for single insert but not working for batch insert. Is there a way to get the auto generated values during the insertion itself.

```
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("insert into table() values()",PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    {
    ps.addBatch();
    }
    ps.executeBatch();
    ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
    List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<Long>();
    while(rs.next()) {
    ids.add(rs.getLong(1));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the auto generated values during the insertion itself.

No. After you `ps.executeBatch()` you need to call `ps.getGeneratedKeys()` and loop through the ResultSet it returns.

Comment: yes i did the same but its not returning the auto generated values.

Comment: there was problem with my sql query i fixed it now it works. thanks